# Raspberry Pi Zero OTG g_mass_storage plug / unplug events

Tags: usb, pi-zero, otg

I have a RaspberryPi Zero connected to my PS4 and want to use it like a smart Network USB stick.
The ultimate goal of my project is, that I want to automatically send data to a specific host in my network when it get's written from my PS4 to the Pi.
To achieve this, I would like to execute a script whenever the PS4 is done interacting with the Pi, which then can handle the network part.

I configured my RaspberryPi using OTG with g_mass_storage mode, which is working fine. The PS4 recognises the Pi as a Mass Storage Gadget and is able to read from / write to it.

But I am stuck at telling when the PS4 is done interacting with the Pi, so that I can safely end the USB connection.

So my question is, how can I tell when the PS4 is starting to interact with the Pi and how can I tell when it is done?

I tried to monitor the contents of `/sys/class/udc/20980000.usb/state`, but it always says `configured`, even when I tell the PS4 that I want to end the connection.

The same goes for `/sys/class/udc/20980000.usb/current_speed`, which always says `high-speed`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can read two things: `I want to be able to automatically send it to another host in my network.` and `How can I tell when the PS4 is starting to interact with the Pi and how can I tell when it is done`. Please add more details on your final goal or clarify this

Comment: Wonder if you can pick up any events via UDEV?  I've seen triggers for USB insert / removal but no idea if anything can be triggered for this.

Comment: @Ephemeral Sorry, I edited the question for clarification. My question is `How can I tell when the PS4 is starting to interact with the Pi and how can I tell when it is done.` I added the other details for context only.

Comment: @Andyroo How would you do this? I tried `udevadm monitor`, but it doesn't log anything.

Comment: Correction: I do get events, but only when issuing `modprobe g_mass_storage` and `modprobe -r g_mass_storage` on the RaspberryPi. What I need are events when I unmount the drive on the target system (PS4).

Comment: If you try to read `/var/log/syslog` when you safely end the USB connection , can you see any useful messages ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. There are some logs directly after adding the g_mass_storage module to the kernel and when physically starting the USB connection, but none afterwards. Not even when I unplug the USB cable.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-udc#L79) I can read for `/sys/class/udc/<udc>/state` : `Indicates current state of the USB Device Controller. Valid
  states are: 'not-attached', 'attached', 'powered',
  'reconnecting', 'unauthenticated', 'default', 'addressed',
  'configured', and 'suspended'; however not all USB Device
  Controllers support reporting all states.`

Comment: Maybe using `libcomposite` for creating your USB widget and using `echo 1 > functions/mass_storage.usb0/lun.0/removable` can do the job... but I can't verify for the moment.

Comment: Maybe you will not see anything as the Pi does not care if it's connected or not... How about checking to see if there is a file lock from the PS4 while it is creating the file that clears when the file write completes - If the box has completed the write is that good enough for you to process the file rather than after the eject?

Comment: I suppose you want do the job with game captures because I think USB 3.0 is require for game copy/move ?